# How does mothership cloak behave while being revealed?

Tags: starcraft-2

If I am being revealed, and my mothership is cloaking my buildings,

1. Are the buildings visible to the opponent?
2. Can the opponent attack the buildings without detection?

Comment: Can you get revealed if you have a mothership *and* buildings?

Comment: I don't see why not... you get revealed when you lose your main building.

Comment: Oh, [you are right](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17045/what-does-player-name-has-not-rebuilt-their-base-and-is-being-revealed-mean). I was under the assumption that you need to lose all buildings to get revealed.

Comment: Losing all buildings is the specific condition for losing the game :)

Comment: That is indeed a very nice question!

Comment: tenfour: Do'h :) Sometimes it just to early for stackexchange

Comment: Please mark an answer as THE answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your Mothership is cloaking your buildings while you are being revealed they will not be able to see them if they hover over the buildings. They will, however, be able to see them on the mini-map. This way they still won't be able to attack the building while you are being revealed.

EDIT: Without detection that is. They won't be able to attack your buildings without Detection.

Comment: This actually isn't true, it is very possible to attack cloaked units without detection.  Any unit that can perform splash damage can attack cloaked buildings/units.  Banelings happen to be the easiest, however, I have seen people send SCVs at a cloaked unit/building and then order a siege tank to attack their SCV.

Comment: I was referring to directly attacking as I am sure the author of the question was referring to as well. If he was asking how to attack cloaked units without using Detection then that would be my obvious answer.

Answer (score 0):

From this quite old TeamLiquid thread, it seems like the buildings will be revealed and attackable:
http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=144315

I didn't test it myself due to being at work though. If i remember, i will test it when i am back home.